# How to use Facebook’s new search graph to find posts with specific words

Tags: facebook, search

I want to query the new search graph to find all of my friends’ posts which contain some word, say `Vacation in Italy`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot do this using the Facebook website itself

But Facebook API does let you do that
How to do it is explained here:

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/)

One of the websites that has implemented this is:
[www.openstatussearch.com](http://www.openstatussearch.com)

[edit]

There are 3 ways of doing this:

Quoting from the link above

> We support search for the following types of objects:
>
> All public posts:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post  This search
>   type does not support limit/offset paging.

1. Now develop your own parser for this data. That's one way of doing this.
2. Using JavaScript SDK
   [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/)
   With the fb.dataquery method. What you want to do is use the stream table to get the status posts for users.
3. Using PHP SDK (I personally prefer this)
   [https:/developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/)
   Decode (using json_decode) the json object recevied by this url:
   [https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Vacation+in+italy&type=post](http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Vacation%20in%20italy&type=post)

Update: Version 2.0 of the GraphAPI does not let you search for posts anymore. See the [updated documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search).

You can continue to search for posts by changing your API call to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=search_query&type=post&access_token={access_token}
```

Comment: Could you say a bit more about how it's done as per your link?

Comment: @batpigandme: Sure, I've edited the post now

Comment: Well done and welcome to SE!

Comment: (Note that the quoted example from the v1.0 API has since been deprecated.)

Answer (score 2):

**Update 30/09/2013:** This is now possible from the Facebook search (Graph Search).

> Starting today, Graph Search will include posts and status updates. Now you will be able to search for status updates, photo captions, check-ins and comments to find things shared with you.

[Source](http://newsroom.fb.com/News/728/Graph-Search-Now-Includes-Posts-and-Status-Updates).

---

The post search is not yet supported, so for the time being you can’t do this.

[image]

What you could do is to try searching for something like `Friends who have been to Italy` or `Friends who have been to Italy and posted photos taken in Italy`. I know, it’s not the same, but it’s the only available option at the moment.

Update: this feature will be implemented in the future, but it’s unknown when will it become available.

> Finally, we are also working on building a completely new vertical to handle searching posts and comments.

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-indexing-and-ranking-in-graph-search/10151361720763920). (It’s buried towards the end of the post.)

Comment: how about searching friends who post apartments for rent in Tel-Aviv?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible at the moment, since you can’t search inside the posts. (And I’m not aware of any related Open Graph verb regarding rentals.)